# Stern-Brocot tree and relative primality

Tags: number-theory

I'm reading through chapter on Number Theory on "Concrete Mathematics" and there is a snippet about [Stern-Brocot tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Brocot_tree) and I'm trying to understand why exactly all fractions in the tree are irreducible. From what I'm reading it follows from the statement that if $m \perp n$  and $m'\perp n'$ and $m'n-mn'=1$ then $m+m' \perp n+n'$ but I don't see why this is true. So why are all fractions irreducible in Stern-Brocot tree?

Comment: Well, $m'n - mn' = (m+m')n - (n+n')m$, so ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s explained in the paragraph that immediately follows identity $(4.31)$, $m'n-mn'=1$, in *Concrete Mathematics*. Specifically, add and subtract $mn$ to get

$$1=m'n-mn'+mn-mn=(m+m')n-(n+n')m\;.\tag{1}$$

Now apply [Bezout’s theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), which says (among other things) that if $a$ and $b$ are non-zero integers, the smallest positive integer that can be written in the form $ak+b\ell$ for integers $k$ and $\ell$ is the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$. This means that if there are integers $k$ and $\ell$ such that $ak+b\ell=1$, then $a$ and $b$ must be relatively prime. Thus, $(1)$ implies that

$$m+m'\perp n+n'\;,$$

as desired.